# retrofit wont return response message (android)

Tags: java, android, retrofit

this is my code:

the interface :

```
public interface LoginAPI {
    @GET("LoginCheck/{username}/{password}/{status}")
    Call<List<Login>> LoginCheck(@Path("username") String username, @Path("password") String password, @Path("status") String status);
}
```

the class:

```
public class Login {
    String username;
    String password;
    String status;
}
```

the main activity :

```
private void LoginCheck() {
        String baseUrl = "http:192.168.169.3:8889/WebService_Indekost/";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        LoginAPI api = retrofit.create(LoginAPI.class);
        Call<List<Login>> result = api.LoginCheck("username", "password", "status");
        result.enqueue(new Callback<List<Login>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Login>> call, Response<List<Login>> response) {
                Log.d("test",response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Login>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Fail", "Fail");
            }
        });
    }
```

when i try to run it, it shows fail instead of the message. note that the response should be in json format. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Log `t.getMessage()` instead of only **"Fail"**.

Comment: i get this when printstacktrace : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto it means the response should be a json array, so the string should be like "[{},{}]", should not be a json object, not like "{...}"

Comment: can i return it in json object then?

Comment: What if you change  `Call<List<Login>>` into `Call<Login>` ?

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto of course you can, it depends what you really want.

Comment: i have changed Call<List<Login>> into Call<Login>, and it doesn't error anymore, but its giving me a "OK" message instead of the json string, how do i get the json string?

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto the json string has convert to `Login` object by Retrofit, you just use `Login` object is ok. use `Login login = response.body();`

Comment: how do i check if the data inside the login? i tried showing it using : Lod.d("test", login.username) but its giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented your error Its saying **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT** means exactly You tried to treat it as an Array which starts with brackets like

```
[ .. data
]
```

But you are not getting a JSON Array, you are getting an Object. So Try changing the API call `Call<List<Login>>` into `Call<Login>`. That may work.

Comment: thats work, but it only return a message "OK", how do i get the json string?

Comment: can you log what response you got ? Do copy and show.

Comment: 04-10 11:45:48.275 26727-26727/com.example.ardisugiarto.learn1 D/GestureDetector: [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
04-10 11:45:48.415 26727-26727/com.example.ardisugiarto.learn1 D/test: OK

Comment: There won't be the data you want Use `response.body()`  instead of`response.message()`. You will get the data you want.

Comment: how do i check if the data inside the login? i tried showing it using : Lod.d("test", login.username) but its giving me error.

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto `response.body()` returns string you cannot assign `Login login = response.body();` directly as you got suggested. Parse that First.

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto OR you can do `call.username`. Im currently in leave for few hours hope you will get it right. Thanks

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto Hi, Have you solved it ? or still some issue left ?

Comment: yeah somehow i got the raw string, it's the problem with my object class. thanks for helping though.

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto Now, Is there any parsing problem ? Or you parsed ?

Comment: i'm still having problem parsing specific value from the json string. it giving me nullpointerexception although my string contain a raw json string.

Comment: OK then post your raw Json you retrieved as it is without missing any characters.. I will help parsing that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `List<Login>` to parse the response, so the response should be a JSON array, like following:

```
[
    {"username":"...","password":"...", "status":"..."},
    {"username":"...","password":"...", "status":"..."},
    {"username":"...","password":"...", "status":"..."}
]
```

if the server return result is like following:

```
{"username":"...","password":"...", "status":"..."}
```

then you should use `Call<Login>` replace `Call<List<Login>>` to parse the response, or, you let server to change its response format to correspond client, it depends what you really want.